# How to get the Blur event to fire for the document on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, events, event-handling, dom-events

Does anyone know how to get the blur event to fire on the document for the iPhone?

I'm trying to get it to fire either when a user changes windows in Safari, or when they open their bookmarks or when they decide to add the page to their homescreen. But none of these are firing it.

Here's my code:

```
    $(document).blur( function () {                 
        document.title = "Ian Taylor";
    });
```

I've tried "document", "window", "'body'". Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to quirksmode, Safari on the iPhone does not fire the "blur" event when the window loses focus.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/

Comment: Is this still true in iOS 7?